# I'm trying to execute my Stored Procedure for some reason it doesn't allow me to

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I've declared the parameters and inserted values in them however it won't allow me to execute my Stored Procedure. Any Help Please will be appreciated. I've tried to execute the Stored procedure in different ways and I still seem to be getting the same error Message.

Procedure  has no parameters and arguments were supplied.

```
USE [ns_lots_of_vlfs]

go

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[RestoreBackups]    Script Date: 16/02/2023 10:49:09 ******/
SET ansi_nulls ON

go

SET quoted_identifier ON

go

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Restorebackups] (@DatabaseName     VARCHAR(500),
                                        @DatabaseNameCopy VARCHAR(5000),
                                        @RestoreDate      DATETIME,
                                        @DiffDate         DATETIME = NULL,
                                        @LogDate          DATETIME = NULL)
AS
    DECLARE @FullBackupSQL                 NVARCHAR(max),
            @DiffBackupSQL                 NVARCHAR(max),
            @LogBackupSQL                  NVARCHAR(max),
            @FullBackupDate                DATETIME,
            @FullBackupFile                NVARCHAR(max),
            @DiffBackupFile                NVARCHAR(max),
            @LogbackupFile                 NVARCHAR(max),
            @FullBackupFileCopy            VARCHAR(5000),
            @FullBackupFileCopyldf         VARCHAR(5000),
            @FullBackupFileCopylocationldf VARCHAR(5000)

    SET nocount ON

    /* Gets the latest full backup to the restore date declared above for the database name declared above.*/
    SELECT TOP 1 @FullBackupFile = bmf.physical_device_name,
                 @FullBackupDate = bs.backup_finish_date
    FROM   msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bmf
           INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset bs
                   ON bs.media_set_id = bmf.media_set_id
    WHERE  bs.type = 'D'
           AND bs.database_name = @DatabaseName
           AND bs.backup_finish_date <= @RestoreDate
    ORDER  BY backup_finish_date DESC

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                  FROM   files
                  WHERE  physical_device_name = @FullBackupFile)
      INSERT INTO files
                  (family_sequence_number,
                   physical_device_name,
                   mirror,
                   backup_set_id,
                   backup_set_uuid)
      SELECT TOP 1 family_sequence_number,
                   physical_device_name,
                   mirror,
                   backup_set_id,
                   backup_set_uuid
      FROM   msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bmf
             INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset bs
                     ON bs.media_set_id = bmf.media_set_id
      WHERE  bs.type = 'D'
             AND bs.database_name = @DatabaseName
             AND bs.backup_finish_date <= @RestoreDate
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT physical_device_name
                             FROM   files
                             WHERE  @FullBackupFile = physical_device_name)
      ORDER  BY backup_finish_date DESC

    /* Gets me the latest full backup to the database name declared above. for the data file path location */
    SELECT TOP 1 @FullBackupFileCopy =
    Replace(sd.physical_name, @DatabaseName, @DatabaseNameCopy)
    FROM   sys.master_files sd
    WHERE  sd.type_desc = 'ROWS'
           AND sd.physical_name LIKE '%.mdf'
           AND sd.NAME = @DatabaseName

    SELECT TOP 1 @FullBackupFileCopylocationldf =
    Replace(sl.physical_name, @DatabaseName, @DatabaseNameCopy)
    FROM   sys.master_files sl
    WHERE  sl.NAME LIKE '%log'
           AND sl.type_desc = 'LOG'
           AND sl.NAME LIKE '%' + @DatabaseName + '%'

    SELECT TOP 1 @FullBackupFileCopyldf = sl.NAME
    FROM   sys.master_files sl
    WHERE  sl.NAME LIKE '%log'
           AND sl.type_desc = 'LOG'
           AND sl.NAME LIKE '%' + @DatabaseName + '%'

    SELECT TOP 1 @DiffDate = bs.backup_finish_date,
                 @DiffBackupFile = bmf.physical_device_name
    FROM   msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bmf
           INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset bs
                   ON bs.media_set_id = bmf.media_set_id
    WHERE  bmf.physical_device_name LIKE '%diff%'
           AND bs.backup_finish_date >= @FullBackupDate
           AND bs.database_name = @DatabaseName
           AND bs.backup_finish_date <= @RestoreDate
           AND bs.type = 'I'
    ORDER  BY backup_finish_date DESC

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                  FROM   files
                  WHERE  physical_device_name = @DiffBackupFile)
      INSERT INTO files
                  (family_sequence_number,
                   physical_device_name,
                   mirror,
                   backup_set_id,
                   backup_set_uuid)
      SELECT TOP 1 family_sequence_number,
                   physical_device_name,
                   mirror,
                   backup_set_id,
                   backup_set_uuid
      FROM   msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bmf
             INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset bs
                     ON bs.media_set_id = bmf.media_set_id
      WHERE  bs.type = 'I'
             AND bs.database_name = @DatabaseName
             AND bs.backup_finish_date <= @RestoreDate
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT physical_device_name
                             FROM   files
                             WHERE  @DiffBackupFile = physical_device_name)
      ORDER  BY backup_finish_date DESC

    SET @FullBackupSQL = 'RESTORE DATABASE ' + @DatabaseNameCopy
                         + '  FROM DISK = ''' + @FullBackupFile
                         + ''' WITH  NORECOVERY,  MOVE '''
                         + @DatabaseName + ''' TO '''
                         + @FullBackupFileCopy + ''', MOVE '''
                         + @FullBackupFileCopyldf + '''   TO '''
                         + @FullBackupFileCopylocationldf
                         + ''' , NORECOVERY,NOUNLOAD, STATS = 5'
    SET @DiffBackupSQL = 'RESTORE DATABASE ' + @DatabaseNameCopy
                         + ' FROM  DISK = ''' + @DiffBackupFile
                         + ''' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5'

    IF Object_id('tempdb..#TempTable_log') IS NOT NULL
      DROP TABLE #temptable_log

    SELECT bmf.family_sequence_number,
           bmf.media_family_id,
           bmf.media_count,
           bmf.logical_device_name,
           bmf.physical_device_name,
           bmf.device_type,
           bmf.physical_block_size,
           bmf.mirror,
           bs.backup_set_id,
           bs.backup_set_uuid,
           bs.first_family_number,
           bs.first_media_number,
           bs.last_family_number,
           bs.last_media_number,
           bs.catalog_family_number,
           bs.catalog_media_number,
           bs.position,
           bs.expiration_date,
           bs.software_vendor_id,
           bs.NAME,
           bs.description,
           bs.user_name,
           bs.software_major_version,
           bs.software_minor_version,
           bs.software_build_version,
           bs.time_zone,
           bs.mtf_minor_version,
           bs.first_lsn,
           bs.last_lsn,
           bs.checkpoint_lsn,
           bs.database_backup_lsn,
           bs.database_creation_date,
           bs.backup_start_date,
           bs.backup_finish_date,
           bs.type,
           bs.sort_order,
           bs.code_page,
           bs.compatibility_level,
           bs.database_version,
           bs.backup_size,
           bs.database_name,
           bs.server_name,
           bs.machine_name,
           bs.flags,
           bs.unicode_locale,
           bs.unicode_compare_style,
           bs.collation_name,
           bs.is_password_protected,
           bs.recovery_model,
           bs.has_bulk_logged_data,
           bs.is_snapshot,
           bs.is_readonly,
           bs.is_single_user,
           bs.has_backup_checksums,
           bs.is_damaged,
           bs.begins_log_chain,
           bs.has_incomplete_metadata,
           bs.is_force_offline,
           bs.is_copy_only,
           bs.first_recovery_fork_guid,
           bs.last_recovery_fork_guid,
           bs.fork_point_lsn,
           bs.database_guid,
           bs.family_guid,
           bs.differential_base_lsn,
           bs.differential_base_guid,
           bs.compressed_backup_size,
           bs.key_algorithm,
           bs.encryptor_thumbprint,
           bs.encryptor_type
    INTO   #temptable_log
    FROM   msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bmf
           INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset bs
                   ON bs.media_set_id = bmf.media_set_id
    WHERE  bs.database_name = @DatabaseName
           AND bs.backup_finish_date <= @RestoreDate
           AND bs.backup_finish_date > @FullBackupDate
           AND bs.backup_finish_date > Isnull(@DiffDate, @FullBackupDate)
           AND bs.type = 'L'

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                  FROM   files
                  WHERE  physical_device_name = @LogbackupFile)
      INSERT INTO files
      SELECT *
      FROM   #temptable_log
      WHERE  physical_device_name NOT IN (SELECT physical_device_name
                                          FROM   files)

    DECLARE @Counter INT

    SET @Counter = 1

    WHILE ( @Counter <= (SELECT Count(*)
                         FROM   #temptable_log) )
      BEGIN
          SELECT TOP 1 @LogbackupFile = physical_device_name,
                       @LogBackupSQL = @LogbackupFile
          FROM   #temptable_log
          WHERE  backup_finish_date > Isnull(@DiffDate, @FullBackupDate)
                 AND backup_finish_date > @FullBackupDate
                 AND backup_finish_date <= @RestoreDate
          ORDER  BY backup_finish_date;

          SET @Counter = 1 -- This should start at one -- 
          /*every time you enter the while loop @counter is a new value so 1 then 2 then 3 and so on which retrieves this from the 
            temp table log.
          */
          SET @LogBackupSQL = 'RESTORE LOG ' + @DatabaseNameCopy
                              + ' FROM  DISK = ''' + @LogbackupFile
                              + ''' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5,'

          DELETE FROM #temptable_log
          WHERE  physical_device_name = @LogbackupFile;
      END

    EXEC master..Sp_executesql
      @FullBackupSQL,
      @DiffBackupSQL,
      @LogBackupSQL
```

I try to execute this

```
USE [ns_lots_of_vlfs]
GO

DECLARE 

     @DatabaseName varchar(500) = 'ns_lots_of_vlfs',
        @DatabaseNameCopy varchar(5000) = 'ns_lots_of_vlfs_COPY',
        @RestoreDate datetime = '2023-02-13 15:45:00.000',
            @DiffDate datetime = null,
        @LogDate datetime = null


EXECUTE [dbo].[RestoreBackups] @DatabaseName, @DatabaseNameCopy, @RestoreDate
GO
```

I get this error message

> Procedure  has no parameters and arguments were supplied.

Comment: Note that a `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` is a sure sign of a flaw. This means that the data engine is free to return what ever arbitrary row(s) it wants, and the row(s) could be different every time you run said query. If you are using `TOP` you need to ensure the query has an `ORDER BY` so that you get consistent and reliable results.

Comment: Many strange things with your `alter procedure`.  The parameters are inside parentheses which is incorrect  and should throw an error. There is also no `begin`.....`end` clause which would cause your proc to only run the first declare statement, and then run the rest after the `alter` causing a multitude of errors.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis - neither of those points are true. The params can be in parentheses if you want and there is no requirement for the body to be in a BEGIN ... END block https://dbfiddle.uk/-lasfrNv

Comment: You can execute the Stored Procedure manually (assuming you're in SSMS) by going to Programmability->Stored Procedures->Left clicking your SP->Execute Stored Procedure.

Comment: There's a reason the `CREATE` or `ALTER` for a procedure needs to be the only statement in the batch, @GeorgeMenoutis , it's because *the entire **batch*** will be used as the definition for the procedure. Even if you put comments prior to the `CREATE`, it will appear in the definition. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/X4nh6oZF)

Comment: Unfortunately we can't run your SQL either, as we don't have the definition for `files`. I doubt, however, we need all that SQL. I suggest you take the time to create a [mre].

Comment: Hi @Larnu, I've created a mini version of this however I am still getting the same error when executing the stored Procedure. https://dbfiddle.uk/2jSJm_Qi

Comment: @Kushal - In your fiddle the stored procedure doesn't have any parameters declared so this is entirely expected https://i.stack.imgur.com/67dGM.png

Comment: Hi @MartinSmith I have just declared the variables and I seem to be having the same error message. https://dbfiddle.uk/pcQcSwGp

Comment: Declaring variables inside a procedure is not the same as defining parameters, @Kushal . You can't assign values to **variables** `DECLARE`d in a procedure, you can only assign value to the **parameters** defined in the `CREATE`/`ALTER` clause.

Comment: @ Martin Smith, Larnu Thanks for the corrections

Comment: Hi @Larnu, I managed to get this working by removing  EXEC master..Sp_executesql
   it was in the wrong place. Thank You.

Comment: That is a different problem and a different question, @Kushal . You should post a new question with an *actual* [mre].

Comment: @Larnu My apologies.